# Adapt ImageView for show picture correctly

Tags: android, image, android-widget, android-imageview

I have some pictures stored on internal storage, that have different sizes and i would like to show it inside a scrollview contains imageview. I would that in each dimension case (image wider than higher, image higher than wider, squared image) image occupy entire screen width.
But code i've write  for do that doesn't work well. If an image is squared or higher than wider everithing works well, but not if image is wider than higher.
this is xml of scrollview

```
<RelativeLayout
   ....
   >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearInsideScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is xml of single imageView that i will inflate inside layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!--
othed widget
-->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is how i fill my view (pics is a list object contains image informations):

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearInsideScroll);

for (int i = 0; i < pics.size(); i++) {
    View new_element = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_element, null,
                false);

    if (pics.get(i).getWidth() > pics.get(i).getHeight()) {
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = width_px;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        } else if (pics.get(i).getWidth() < pics.get(i).getHeight()) {
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = height_px;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        }

        else {
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = width_px;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = width_px;
        }
    linearLayout.addView(new_element);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the imageView, set scaleType.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: it doesn't work. If i use FIT_XY, image is stretched only horizontally